# Real-time changes on IDE/Assembler

Tags: ide, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ollydbg, cheat-engine

> I'm new on this, sorry for bad usage of terms or overextending an explanation. I'm learning code languages and way i found to bring it to my world so i can learn it better, was coding for/with games i play.

---

When a window close on the game a function needs to be called, when the character move or you pick an item, everything has a command, function, process or some value of an address change and etc... What i wanted to know is if there something that shows me on real time every call, every value change, address value change, etc...

Nowdays i have to reach some value address by CheatEngine, changing the value till i find the correct address. With this kind of thing i would have a list off things that is happening right now, and a "log" of the past things, then i go to the exact time that i did something, so i would have to look on that peace of the list and discover what did my "something"

1. Click on a button;
2. Check on the real-time thing what happened at the time of the "Click
   on a button" process;
3. Discover what call was responsible for that and what it did;
4. Now i can code something that do what "Click on a button" do, without needing to actually click on that button;

---

I have seen it somewhere, thats why i'm asking here, if i'm totally wrong and this doesn't exist, i'm sorry, i will delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a Debugger is what your looking for.

The Debugger in Visual Studio does exactly what your describing, you can see the real time values of your variables and objects at any stage in your program.

You can set 'Break Points' that will halt your code wherever you put them, allowing you to inspect your variables.

You can also 'Step' through your code, which will go line by line through your code, stopping at each line to allow you to inspect.

Here is a good page for an overview of debugging in Visual Studio 2017:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but it is not on MY program, it is in a game or any other software, as far as i know it's related with assembling, diasembling, IDE, and things like that, but i'll give a try on VS and see it it can do the same

Comment: I should of mentioned this in the first place, you might want to look into developing games with Unity. I feel like it might suit you very well, they have absolutely free tutorials ranging from extreme basics to advanced techniques. Here's the link to their website: https://unity3d.com/